# Ioredis with Laradock redis container Connect Timeout

Tags: laravel, redis, laradock

I have an App built on Laravel.
I'm using **Laradock** and I'm trying to use **Redis  container**, but I have a problem with connection.

With the command:

```
docker inspect laradock_redis_1
```

I can see that: **"IPAddress": "172.22.0.2",**

By In my frontend I'm trying to connect to Redis with ioredis:

```
import Redis from 'ioredis';
const redis = new Redis({
                 port: 6379,
                 host: 172.22.0.2,
                 password: "password"
               });
redis.on('pmessage', function(subscribed, channel, message) {
...
})
```

But I can't connect because I get this error:

> [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

I'm trying also with change ip and port like:

```
port: 6379,
host: 127.0.0.1,
```

Or changing the port on docker-compose with 1111 but it doesn't work yet.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Front you mean frontend JS (accesible by user)? or a nodejs server?

If nodejs server try removing passwrod.

Comment: frontend accessible by user.

Comment: I tried to delete password but I had te same error

Comment: @Lorezo you should't connect to redis from frondend JS, this should be done on nodejs serverside.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the container ip address you can the `name of the container` or if you are using `docker-compose.yml` you can use the `name of the service` instead of ip address. So something along these lines would work:

```
const redis = new Redis({
                 port: 6379,
                 host: laradock_redis_1
               });
```

Comment: thankyou for answer, but it return error.  [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND and then [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT